# Synchronize update across cluster

Tags: servlets, websphere, cluster-computing

I have a web application that maintains a version flag as a ServletContext.setAttribute('flag', flagValue)

A Filter uses this flagValue in its doFilter method applied to diff servlets.

There is a notification service which toggles the value of the 'flag'.

Now I need to deploy this app in a clustered environment. Given the fact that ServletContext is per JVM, how do I propagate the update received on the notification url across the multiple servers in the cluster?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745049/j2ee-application-scoped-variables-in-a-clustered-environment-websphere

Comment: @dbreaux I am thinking on similar lines - notifying individual AppServer urls... unless someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up notifying individual AppServer urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynacaches DistributedMap to share the value across the cluster, then the other servers just need to check for changes when they would be affected by it.